# What distro for this task?

Tags: distribution-choice

Requirements:

- firewall
- internet connection sharing
- DHCP server
- Freenet (Sun Java)
- torrent
- Samba
- SSH server
- Take up as little RAM as possible.
- Must be 100% usable in console (remotely over ssh).

Comment: I would find a distro you can set up and then make it do what you want. most distro's don't use much ram, at least not if you turn X off.

Comment: Which distros have you tried so far (apart from Arch)?

Comment: I can help with Arch, to some extent. I run my server with it, and my desktop.

Comment: Fedora - since it has rock solid stability and extensive community support. That said, most distros use very less RAM. I would just recommend using a distro with great community support like Fedora, Ubuntu, Debian.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to make a good recommendation. Almost any linux distro could be configured for that scenario. Can you add anything more to the picture like hardware, interaction with other systems, your experience with other distros, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and pick a distro with an active support community such as Fedora or Ubuntu. For some one with little experience (or a lot) it can be an invaluable tool. Most likely someone else has had your same (or a similar) problem. With Fedora I regularly use sites such as fedoraforum.org and stackexchange sites (of course).

They all can perform those functions for the most part, but something like Fedora is always easy to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Any Linux distro can do all what you need. If you need a more desktop oriented system I would recommend Fedora or Mandriva, if you need a more corporate oriented system I would recommend CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD - maximum flexibility, functions, lots of programs, lots of manuals. Easy to install following instructions. Easy to install any programs.